# I have problem with "Re-Send?" text wrapping on textview

Tags: ios, swift, word-wrap

"I have label that text is "Don't receive Verification code ? Re-Send?", Here I am using word wrapping . But while un wrapping it is coming "Send?" in next line ,I need alway  "Re-Send?" together either it is after "?"  (Don't receive Verification code ? Re-Send?) or in next line as "Re-send?"., Can anybody suggest me how to solve this ?"

If i use "Re_Send" then it is coming next line but if i use "Re-Send" the word is splitting.

```
let attributeText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Don't you get 
verificationcode in your email Inbox? ", attributes: 
[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red, 
NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 
22),NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: style])


attributeText.append(NSAttributedString(string: " Re-Send ", 
attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green, 
NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 22)]))

let linkRange = attributeText.mutableString.range(of: " Re-Send ")
    attributeText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: 
linkKey, range: linkRange)


txtview.attributedText = attributeText
txtview.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
txtview.textAlignment = .center
```

I need it should be either "Don't you get verificationcode in your email Inbox? Re-Send?"   OR "Don't you get verificationcode in your email Inbox? 
Re-Send? " .  (Depends on my screen length).

Comment: Use a nonbreaking hyphen. https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `‑` (U+2011 NON-BREAKING HYPHEN) instead of `-` (U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS).

```
attributeText.append(NSAttributedString(string: " Re‑Send ",
```

or

```
attributeText.append(NSAttributedString(string: " Re\u{2011}Send ",
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let string  = "\u{2011}"
attributeText.append(NSAttributedString(string: " Re\(string)Send ", 
attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green, 
NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 22)]))
let linkRange = attributeText.mutableString.range(of: " Re\(string)Send ")
attributeText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: linkKey, range: 
linkRange)
```

Comment: I suggest renaming `string` to `hyphen` or `nbhyphen`. `string` is too vague.